# Tomcat 8 игнорирует /META-INF/context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat

Имеется /META-INF/context.xml с таким содержанием.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/battleship"/>
```

Делаю деплой приложения так: mvn tomcat7:deploy.
В итоге в папке с приложениями webapps появляется WAR файл c именем Battleship-Web.war. Но приложение не запускается по адресу localhost:8080/battleship, оно запускается по УРЛ localhost:8080/Battleship-Web - т.е. по имени файла.[гайд по контексту томката читал](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)

Вот что я делал:

- удалил файлы из conf/Catalina/localhost. Там был мусор от прошлых проектов (не знаю, откуда он там)
- в файле server.xml поставил autoDeploy="false"
- в файле server.xml Дописал элементу Host атрибут deployOnStartup="false". В этом случае деплой приложения вообще перестал происходить, мавен выдавал ошибку. Удалил этот атрибут.

Как мне заставить, чтобы томкат видел /META-INF/context.xml файл моих приложений?

Comment: А если override="true" добавить?

Comment: эта проблема была актуальна в апреле. сегодня июнь. боюсь я уже забыл что за ерунда была

Answer (score 1):

Если вы читали гайд по контексту томката, то должны были там увидеть текст

> This attribute must only be used when statically defining a Context in server.xml. In all other circumstances, the path will be inferred from the filenames used for either the .xml context file or the docBase.

Т.к. вы не прописываете его в `server.xml`, то и работать ничего не должно.

Я могу предложить задать путь для деплоя в pom.xml, пример есть тут https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html